# How to fix RewriteRule recursion?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, activesync

I am running tine (tine20.org) on an Ubuntu 12.04 server using Plesk to configure it. In Plesk I have a subdomain (tine.mydomain.com). In the webserver configuration of this subdomain I added those lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync(.*) /index.php?frontend=activesync [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
```

I copied it from the Tine wiki: https://www.tine20.org/wiki/index.php/Admins/Synchronisation

When I try to connect to tine.mydomain.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync I get an Error 500 and in the log those lines:

```
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 2.206.3.119] r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 2.206.3.119] redirected from r->uri = /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
[Fri Nov 21 19:46:36 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 2.206.3.119] Zlib: Compressed 621 to 379 : URL /phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/phppath/cgi_wrapper/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
```

So there's some kind of recursion but I don't know why and how to fix it. How do I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps put the `^` anchor before the pattern so that it matches only if it is the first part of the string.

Comment: That seems to work. No it doesn't accept the user name, but I guess it's a different issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .htaccess and give it a try

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Have you reloaded or restarted apache?

```
/etc/init.d/apache reload
```

If you have to put this in between your virtualhost but you should put this in your .htaccess of the directory where you're trying to access.

I'm hoping your have your virtualhost/tine.mydomain.com setup correctly to have these rules in your .httpd conf.

Comment: I don't have to set it manually. I have a web interface where I have an input field in which I can add new settings.

Comment: use fetcher like wget or curl to do the testing on your actual url call. see what you get.